# Creating new Activity while service is running

Tags: android, telephony

How to start new activity when incoming call is detected. In the code below I want to start new Activity at `CALL_STATE_RINGING` state

```
public String getCurrentCallState(final TelephonyManager mytelMgr) {
        int callState = mytelMgr.getCallState();
        String callStateString = "NOTKNOWN";
        switch (callState) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                callStateString = "IDLE";
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                callStateString = "OFFHOOK";
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                callStateString = "RINGING";
                break;
         }
}
```

Now I made some changes In the ***CALL_STATE_RINGING*** state But it is not working. Whenever call is coming my app is quitting.
Actually I want to call that activity while incoming call rings.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class CallHelper extends Activity
{


    /**
     * Listener to detect incoming calls. 
     */
    private class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
    {


        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) 
        {

            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                // called when someone is ringing to this phone
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), out.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);   //must be provided
                getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);



            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Incoming: "+incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Broadcast receiver to detect the outgoing calls.
     */
    public class OutgoingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public OutgoingReceiver() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Outgoing: "+number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    private Context ctx;
    private TelephonyManager tm;
    private CallStateListener callStateListener;

    private OutgoingReceiver outgoingReceiver;

    public CallHelper(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;

        callStateListener = new CallStateListener();
        outgoingReceiver = new OutgoingReceiver();
    }

    /**
     * Start calls detection.
     */
    public void start() {
        tm = (TelephonyManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL);
        ctx.registerReceiver(outgoingReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    /**
     * Stop calls detection.
     */
    public void stop() {
        tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
        ctx.unregisterReceiver(outgoingReceiver);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference - except for one important flag - when launching an `Activity` from a `Service` or even `BroadcastReceiver`. Use the following in your *CALL_STATE_RINGING* case:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);   //must be provided
getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);
```

Make sure your launching activity is defined in **AndroidManifest** too.